# R: Can I have date and text format in same column in data.frame?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, date, format

In my excel sheet, I have a column of dates.
Some of these are accurately described (**1**):
Ex. "2020-06-11" - and defined as dates in excel.
Some are generally described (**2**):
Ex. "2012" or "May 2006" - and defined as general in excel.

**I would like to read the sheet to a data.frame, dat, where 1 is in date format and 2 is in text format within the same column, dat$dates** - or at least just express the dates as are in any format (show both 2020-06-11 and May 2006 in dat$dates).

*The issue:*

If I read the file as dates:

```
type <- c('date') 
dat <- read_excel("file.xlsx", col_types = filter)
```

**1** Has desired format (ex. 2020-06-11), but **2** is NA

If I read the file as text:

```
type <- c('text') 
dat <- read_excel("file.xlsx", col_types = filter)
```

**1** Has "strange" format (ex. 38811), but **2** has desired format (ex. 2012 and May 2006)

**How do I get both accurate dates (2020-06-11) and unprecise dates (May 2006) to appear in dat$dates?**

Thanks for the read!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and sorry to be bearer of bad news to you:  You cannot.  A `data.frame` is a _list_ of columns that are constrained to _all have the same length_ and where _each column is of one type only_.  For things like dates or dates and times, I sometimes resort to two columns of more internal representation (for example `Datetime` as the `numeric` it is) as well as an added 'formatted' column for human consumption.

Comment: Maybe you can create a custom type in the Format Cell.